# Using integer with multiple values in Form API

Tags: 7, nodes, forms, entities

I have an integer field on a node which can take two values. The nodes are created by the users by submitting a form. I can't work out how to do this for a multiple field text value.

How do I set-up a textfield form element to take multiple values?
How do I then submit it into the node using an entity wrapper?

This is the form element.

```
function createnode_form($form, &$form_state){    
    $form['field_student_age'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('test'),
    ); .....
```

This is the code that creates the new node.

```
function postajob_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

  $entity = entity_create('node', $values);
  $ewrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $entity);

  $ewrapper->field_salary->set($form_state['values']['field_salary']);
```

There is no multiple property for textfields. Do I need to open up a different path in the form variable (e.g. `$form['field_student_age']['value1']`)? I've tried various options but I can't work out what the path would be.

If I do that, can I then just submit it in the wrapper with the extended path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution from [Save a new value with entity_metadata_wrapper to an entity field which is an array](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50358/save-a-new-value-with-entity-metadata-wrapper-to-an-entity-field-which-is-an-arr).

I created two separate form fields.

```
function createnode_form($form, &$form_state){ 
  $form['field_student_age'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('test'),
  );

  $form['field_student_age2'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('test2'),
  );
```

Then I stored them using the first method in the post quoted above.

```
$ewrapper->field_student_age[] = $form_state['values']['field_student_age'];
$ewrapper->field_student_age[] = $form_state['values']['field_student_age2'];
```

Rather than using `set` as I'd done with single values, I created a new entry for each value using `[] =`.