# Using Entity Metadata Wrapper to set/get value from custom field added via Field API to custom entity type

Tags: 7, entities

My question is related to: [Using entity metadata wrapper with custom entity type](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/173170/using-entity-metadata-wrapper-with-custom-entity-type)

I know that I should inform EMW how to work with entity properties via [hook_entity_property_info_alter](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_property_info_alter/7)

but what about custom fields added via Field API to custom entity. I'm trying to set value of that kind of field via EMW but after entity save, field (db table) is always empty.

Comment: Field types that EMW knows about should be handled automatically I think, is this a custom field type?

Comment: This is a entityreference field type (to user entity). Creation code is in related question.

Comment: @Clive I've forgotten to set fieldable => true in entity definition hook. Now EMW works.

Comment: That would probably make a useful self-answer, I can imagine others missing the same thing

Answer (score 1):

I've forgotten to set `fieldable => true` in [hook_entity_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info/7). Now EMW works