# How to set multiple list values via Entity Metadata Wrapper?

Tags: 7, entities

Field creation code:

```
if (! field_info_field(MY_FIELD_NAME)) {

    field_create_field(array(
        'field_name => MY_FIELD_NAME,
        'type' => 'list_integer',
        'settings' => array(
            'allowed_values' => some_allowed_values(),
        ),
        'cardinality' => FIELD_CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED,
    ));

    field_create_instance(array(
        'field_name' => MY_FIELD_NAME,
        'entity_type' => MY_ENTITY_NAME,
        'bundle' => MY_ENTITY_BUNDLE_NAME,
        'widget' => array(
            'type' => 'options_select',
        )
    ));

}
```

Setter code:

```
//posted options are list values keys e.g (3,4)
$wrapper->{MY_FIELD_NAME}->set(array_values($values['posted_options']));
//not work too:
$wrapper->{MY_FIELD_NAME}->set($values['posted_options']);
$wrapper->{MY_FIELD_NAME}->set(array($values['posted_options']));
//in for loop
$wrapper->{MY_FIELD_NAME}[] = $option_key;
```

Error:

> EntityMetadataWrapperException: Invalid data value given. Be sure it
>   matches the required data type and format. in
>   EntityMetadataWrapper->set()

or

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type EntityValueWrapper as array

It works only when I set single value:

```
$wrapper->{MY_FIELD_NAME}->set($option_key);
```

This is not related to: [Using entity metadata wrapper with custom entity type](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/173170/using-entity-metadata-wrapper-with-custom-entity-type)

because this is different field type.

Found solution:

```
   field_create_field(array(
        'field_name' => MY_FIELD_NAME,
        'type' => 'list_integer',
        'settings' => array(
            'allowed_values' => options_values(),
        ),
        'default_widget' => 'options_select',
        'default_formatter' => 'list_default',
        'cardinality' => FIELD_CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED,
    ));

    field_create_instance(array(
        'field_name' => MY_FIELD_NAME,
        'entity_type' => MY_ENTITY_NAME,
        'bundle' => MY_ENTITY_BUNDLE_NAME,
        'widget' => array(
            'type' => 'options_select',
            'formatter' => 'list_default',
        )
    ));
```

Comment: @ar7max no, it's a different question. other field type.

Comment: ok, but I need moderator's response

Comment: I agree with the dup on this.  You asked two question about custom fields w/ EFQ on back to back days, and I don't see what the difference is between the two?