# Set value of file field using entity_metadata_wrapper non working

Tags: entities, files

I have a custom entity with a file field accepting multiple values.
I would like to set file values according to
https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/entity-api/entity-metadata-wrappers#example-value-set-save but none of the two methods are working here.
I always get this error

```
error  php  Error: Call to a member function set() on null in include().
```

I am running Drupal 7, `file_entity` module enabled. Here follows the code:

```
$file = file_load(8172);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('sys_ind', 13718);
$wrapper->field_allegati->file->set( $file );
$wrapper->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed! Thanks to this post [Save a new value with entity_metadata_wrapper to an entity field which is an array](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50358/save-a-new-value-with-entity-metadata-wrapper-to-an-entity-field-which-is-an-arr/64347#64347)

```
$file = file_load(8172);
$node = entity_load('sys_ind', array(13718));
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('sys_ind', '13718');

$wrapper->field_allegati[NULL]->file->set( $file ); # This worked

$wrapper->save();
```

so the fix is using `NULL` (at least in multivalue field like mine is), not 0 or any other index nor `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to see if it works:

```
$wrapper->field_allegati[0] = (array) $file;
```

The wrapper seems to struggle with file fields

Comment: nope, just tried, error changes to `EntityMetadataWrapperException: Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required data type and format. Value at                           [error]
sys_ind(13718)->field_allegati: array (
  0 =>`